# How can I create a Simple page that display the latest node of a content type?

Tags: nodes

I write a little module for loading the content via ajax([one of the used tutorials](http://www.seanbuscay.com/ajax-reader-demo/)) and now I need a page for the first visiting(front page). I don't want to do this with Views and looked around, but didn`t found a simple solution for this.

So, I extend the hook_menu () function with:

**EDITED**

```
$items['first-node'] = array(
  'page callback' => 'first_node_callback',
  'access callback' => TRUE, //EDIT -> 'user_access' creates Menu error
  'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
);
```

and the callback:

```
function first_node_callback() {
  $query = db_select("node", "n");
  $query->fields('n', array('nid'))
    ->condition("type", "mytype", "=") 
    ->orderBy("created", "DESC")
    ->range(0, 1); 
  $nids = $query->execute()->fetchCol();
  $nodes = node_load_multiple($nids);
  return node_view_multiple($nodes, 'full');
}
```

**EDITED END**

Should i load this in the #markup or use a normal return or need i an extra theme output? I'm little bit confused with the possibilities!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do the following with node object in your page callback function. No need of returning separate `#markup`.

```
return drupal_render(node_view($node));
```

Comment: Thx for your fast answer, but i get some errors with this line. Notice: Undefined variable: node in first_node_callback(), Warning: Creating default object from empty value in node_build_content()

Comment: @Bruno The code will only work when you have the valid `$node` object loaded. Try printing the `$node` after the `node_load()` function.

Comment: I edit my post, with this code i get an white site and no errors are shown in log.

Comment: @Bruno Add `return 'hello world';` outside the `if` loop and check. Looks like the control isn't going inside the loop.

Comment: I had some errors in db_select and edit it. Now should it works.